# What is the name of this special subset of module over commutative ring with unity

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, commutative-algebra, modules

Let $R$ ba a commutative ring with unity and let $M$ be a $R$-module. For each $m,n\in M$ consider free spaces $\bar{m}$ and $\bar{n}$ generated respectively by $m$ and $n,$ i.e $$\bar{m}=Lin_{R}\{m\}=\{rm:r\in R\}\hspace{5pt}\text{and}\hspace{5pt}\bar{n}=Lin_{R}\{n\}=\{rn:r\in R\}.$$
Additionally let the $\phi_{m,n}:\bar{m}\rightarrow\bar{n}$ be $R$ linear and such that $$\phi_{m,n}(m)=n$$
whenever it can be constructed.
Define a following set $$M^!:=\{m\in M:\forall(n\in M)(\phi_{m,n}\text{ can be constructed and is an epimorphism})\}.$$
My question is about a name of this set. More, where can I find some information about it?

---

EDIT

After the Matt Samuel's comment I feel that saying: "$\phi_{m,n}$ is en epimorphism" is redundant.

Comment: $\phi_{m,n}$ will not extend to a homomorphism in general.

Comment: For example, suppose the module over $\mathbb{Z}$ is $\mathbb{Z}_3\oplus \mathbb{Z}_2$. Then there's no $\mathbb{Z}$-linear map sending $(1,0)$ to $(0,1)$.

Comment: But $M^!$ is well definied when we consider $\phi_{m,n}$ which can be constructed. I will edit question. THX

Comment: Let $I={\rm Ann}_R(m)$ and $J={\rm Ann}_R(n)$. The would-be map $Rm\to Rn:m\mapsto n$ corresponds to a would-be map $R/I\to R/J:r+I\mapsto r+J$, which is well-defined iff $I\subseteq J$. Thus, anything that annihilates $m$ must annihilate all $n\in R$ in order for $\phi$ to exist, and so $$M^!=\{m\in M:{\rm Ann}_R(m)={\rm Ann}_R(M)\}.$$ For $\Bbb Z$-modules, $M^!$ is the set of elements of maximal order.

Comment: @anon Can you clarify the notion "...corresponds to..." ? I still have a problem with verifying the existance of map between modules.

Comment: You know that $Rx\cong R/{\rm Ann}_R(x)$ right? Since ${\rm Ann}_R(x)$ is the kernel of the obvious $R$-module homomorphism $R\to Rx$ given by $r\mapsto rx$. Simply rewrite $Rm\to Rn$ as a map $R/I\to R/J$.